# Help diagnosing weird migration problem

Tags: ee2, migration

I would value any suggestions / help available regarding a weird problem I'm having with an EE migration.

Trying to create a clone of an existing site (that works just fine) to do some development to the site templates.

I've set up a clean build of EE 2.10.1 on the development server, and it works just fine.

I've moved all the ancillary files associated with the existing site (e.g. Templates, Add-ons etc.) to the development server, and they are all visible and / or in the right place.  But I've retained the (working) config.php and database.php files from the initial setup of the new machine.

I've exported the MySQL of existing site using phpmyadmin - a process I've used before and works fine.

I edit the MySQL dump to remove table relating to CECache (which points to cache entries I did not migrate across).

I've imported the exported MySQL tables into the MySQL of the newly created server.

I try to log into the CP and get no further than the login screen looping back after each attempt.

I've had a look and it appeared that the 'new' site was trying to load some assets from the old site - presumably due to settings in the imported MySQL (as config.php and database.php remain unchanged and relate only to new site).

So I reload the original database for new site, and check it works as before.

I edit the MySQL dump to change all references in there to the old site (or the old file path) to the new site URL / site path.

I try importing the edited MySQL to the new site database, and try to log in, and get same error as before - but this time the new site is not trying to load assets from the old site.

All the fixes I can find for this assume / suggest it is a problem with settings in the config.php file.  But in this case, as I have a working config.php, the error must be something that is introduced via the MySQL import - not sure what though.

Anyone with any ideas?  Would value any / all suggestions about how to fix.

Thanks!

Comment: follow this tutorial, it may help: http://www.creat-ee.com/tutorials/more/migrating_your_ee_site_to_live_server

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

- Does the site remove the index.php? If so, did you import the
  .htaccess file and are there any directory customisations in there?
- In config.php, check these variables:
- cp_url
- site_label
- base_url
- ce_image
- in /index.php, are there any custom config values you might
  have forgotten?